# Not found /proc/self/maps for QNX plaform

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory, qnx, memory-mapping

We have a code written for Linux, where we are parsing the maps file using std::ifstream ifs("/proc/self/maps");. I am porting that code for QNX platform where I can see the /proc/self/ folder is available but the maps file is not available.

- Who is creating the /proc/self/maps file in Linux?
- How to make this code work in QNX platform?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the map is not available? How did you verify that?

Comment: @cad : I have written the program to check all he directory and files available in /proc/self/, but did not shown maps file. Also as mention above std::ifstream ifs("/proc/self/maps")
ifs.is_open() returns false for QNX platform device and return true for Linux.

Comment: Answered in the below thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587285/retrieving-the-memory-map-of-its-own-process-in-qnx/34628724#34628724

Answer (score 0):

This file in Linux contains map of memory of the process: code, data, heap, loaded shared libraries etc. If you can explain what you need to do with this, someone could suggest how to achieve same on QNX.
Consider that QNX belongs to the BSD family, its low level stuff is not like in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Similar thing would be /proc/self/as

See usage sample here:
https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0SP1.update/com.qnx.doc.neutrino_cookbook/s3_procfs.html#DCMD_PROC_MAPINFO